# Change div data-href value

Tags: jquery

I try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".fb-like").attr('data-href',encodeURIComponent(location.href));
   });
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana"></div>
```

But data-href is empty.

Comment: Check the console, do you get any error ? Have you loaded the jquery library ?

Comment: No, don't have errors and I loaded the jquery library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works, Ive just tried it:

http://jsfiddle.net/MeE7B/

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="verdana">
  pippo
</div>"
```

After running the example inspect "pippo" with firebug or similar and you will see the attribute with correct value.

Answer (score 2):

I retrieved `data-href` through `$('.fb-like').data('href')` and it seems to work for me. 
check this out :http://jsfiddle.net/TFF2Z/1/

Anyway is a good solution to set `data` attributes like this :

```
$('.some-class').data('some-attr','some-value');
```

and then retrieve through

```
$('.some-class').data('some-attr');
```